# Call Put method from blade

Tags: laravel

I am working in Laravel 5.2 and I am trying with simple CRUD.. In the form where I am supposed to edit the details. In the blade I have the following code `{{Form::open(['method'=>'PUT','route'=>['account_update',$data[0]['ms_id']] ])}}`

In routes file I have defined the account_update as follows

```
Route::put('account_update/{id}',['as'=>'account_update/{id}','uses'=>'BAMasterAccountController@update_account']);
```

When I run the code I get an error in blade saying the route is not defined.

Kindly help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the route name to `account_update`:

```
'as' => 'account_update'
```